# How to GET database to call table and its contents in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-apps-script, google-maps-markers

I'm using Laravel 9, PHP 8. I want to retrieve data from a database table with javascript, please help.
So I want to pin point location using google maps from my table database using `$locations`?

This is the content (meanwhile I still using markers manually) :

```
@extends('layouts.sinlanding')
@section('container')
<!-- Page Heading -->
<h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">GOOGLE MAPS</h1>
<div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    @foreach ($data as $item)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap() {
            const myLatLng = { lat: -8.636176573413225, lng: 117.23647409339307 }; 
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatLng,
            });

            $locations = [
            ['Pelabuhan Bima', -8.446268919183991, 118.71370024353398],
            ['Pelabuhan Lembar', -8.729112623725898, 116.07243886556259],
            ];
  
            var locations = $locations;
  
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  
            var marker, i;
              
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                  });
                    
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                  })(marker, i));
  
            }
        }
  
        window.initMap = initMap;
    </script>
    @endforeach
  
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAP_KEY') }}&callback=initMap" ></script>
  
@endsection
```

This is the controller :

```
<?php
      
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
      
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
    use App\Models\Pelabuhan;
      
    class GoogleController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Write code on Method
         *
         * @return response()
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $data = Pelabuhan::all();
            return view('sinkopel', [
                'data' => $data,
                'title' => 'Home'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I try this but it doesnt work :

```
$locations = [
    [$item->nama_pelabuhan, $item->latitude ',' $item->longitude],
];
```

Comment: `it doesnt work`...because that's PHP code, not Javascript. It needs to be in a PHP block, for a start, in order to execute. Then you need to make PHP _output_ content which Javascript could understand. Generally the easiest way is to generate some JSON using `json_encode`, since JS can interpret that as an object literal.

Comment: `$item->latitude ',' $item->longitude` isn't valid PHP syntax and will throw a syntax error. It should be `$item->latitude, $item->longitude`. However, as the first comment already states, your current implementation of `$location` is in a JS context, not PHP.

Comment: $locations = [
    [{{$item->nama_pelabuhan}}, {{$item->latitude}},{{ $item->longitude]}},
];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the locations array and pass it to the view.

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Pelabuhan::all();

    $locations = [];

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $locations[] = [
            $item->nama_pelabuhan,
            $item->latitude,
            $item->longitude
        ];
    }

    return view('sinkopel', [
        'locations' => $locations,
        'title' => 'Home'
    ]);
}
```

In the view, use the JSON form of the locations

```
@extends('layouts.sinlanding')
@section('container')
<!-- Page Heading -->
<h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">GOOGLE MAPS</h1>
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {
    const myLatLng = { lat: -8.636176573413225, lng: 117.23647409339307 };
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: myLatLng,
    });

    var locations = {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($locations) }};

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
window.initMap = initMap;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAP_KEY') }}&callback=initMap">
</script>
@endsection
```

Documentation on [Rendering JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#rendering-json) in blade.

Comment: You can skip that foreach by selecting only required columns and converting them to an array. `Pelabuhan::select('nama_pelabuhan','latitude','longitude')->get()->toArray();`

Comment: @nice_dev, Yes that is also a way to achieve the goal.

Comment: I try the code above but it says 'Undefined variable $locations'
var locations = {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($locations) }};

Comment: @Karls23 Aren't you passing the variable `$locations` from the controller to the view as shown in this answer?